# how to format a date to yyyy/mm/dd in af:column adf table?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

i have af:table which have af:coulmn which contain Date .

the date is displayed on the format  of mm/dd/yyyy  : 7/16/2018

i want to display at as yyyy/mm/dd 2018/7/16

```
<af:column sortProperty="depositeDate" sortable="false" width="10%"
                 headerText="#{bundle.deposite_Date_Label}">
        <af:outputText value="#{row.depositeDate}"/>
</af:column>
```

how to achive that ?

Comment: lookup <af:convertDateTime>, similar to <af:convertNumber>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DefaultDateFormatter` to achieve this:

```
DefaultDateFormatter ddf = new DefaultDateFormatter();
String depositeDate = ddf.format("yyyy/MM/dd, depositeDatePlain);
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `<af:outputText>` add the `<af:convertDateTime>` tag, so your code should look like the following:

`<af:column sortProperty="depositeDate" sortable="false" width="10%"
                 headerText="#{bundle.deposite_Date_Label}">
        <af:outputText value="#{row.depositeDate}">
            <af:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
        </af:outputText>
</af:column>`

For reference about convertDateTime tag check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E12419_09/tagdoc/af_convertDateTime.html).

PS: row.depositeDate needs to be a Date object, not a String!